# Given that $a$ $|$ $n$ and $b$ $|$ $n$, show that: $ab$ $|$ $an,bn$ iff $ab$ $|$ $\gcd(an,bn)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Given that $a$ $|$ $n$ and $b$ $|$ $n$, show that: $ab$ $|$ $an,bn$ iff $ab$ $|$ $\gcd(an,bn)$.

I can see that $a|n$ and $b|n$ implies $ab|an,bn$, but I can't figure how to relate it to $ab|\gcd(an,bn)$.

I know that $ab$ is a divisor of $an$ and $bn$ but I can't see how I'd show that it's a divisor of the greatest common divisor of $an$ and $bn$.

Comment: Not following.  since $b$ divides $n$ we can write $n=bB$.  Thus $an=abB$ hence $ab$ divides $an$.  Similarly $ab$ divides $bn$.  No other conditions needed.  Moreover, if $d$ divides both $r$ and $s$ then $d$ divides $\gcd(r,s)$.

Comment: Why not ask for clarification on the answer from which this is lifted? I feel it  does not make much sense as a standalone question.

Comment: To unpack @lulu's Comment, this is really immediate from the definition of "greatest common divisor".  The thing $ab$ divides both things $an$ and $bn$, so it must divide their greatest common divisor, $\gcd(an,bn)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need $\,a,b\mid n.\,$ The equivalence is the characteristic (universal)  propery of the gcd

$$ c\mid a,b \iff c\mid (a,b)$$

**Proo**f $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ By Bezout $\, (a,b) = ja\! +\! kb\,$ for $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z,\,$ so $\,c\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid ja\!+\!kb=(a,b)$

$\ (\Leftarrow)\  \ \ c\mid (a,b)\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid a,b\ $ by transitivity of divisiblity. $\  $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ This property characterizes the gcd, i.e. if $\,c\mid a,b \iff c\mid d\,$ then $\,d = (a,b).\,$  Indeed, if we choose $\,c = d\,$ then $\ (\Leftarrow)\ $ yields $\,d\mid a,b,\,$ i.e. $\,d\,$ is a *common* divisor of $\,a,b.\,$  Further  $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ shows that $\,d\,$ is divisible by every common divisor $\,c\,$ of $\,a,b,\,$ so $\,d\ge c,\,$ therefore $\,d\,$ is the *greatest* common divisor of $\,a,b.$